# Marketing cloud. Is it possible to get Job data (like email name , subject ) via wsproxy

Tags: marketing-cloud

Normally in Marketing cloud we have following data view

1. _Job --> This give us the job Id ,

we use this jobid to connect sent, opens, click , bounce and unsub. I am trying to get data for an account since inception using wsproxy into a data extension .

I am using an article from Zuzanna (

> https://sfmarketing.cloud/2019/11/09/retrieve-tracking-data-since-account-inception-using-wsproxy/

)

This is good article , but i am not able to get the info about email subject or information which we generally have _Jobs data view inorder to provide the context of sent.

is there any way that wsproxy can be used to get _job like data for period before 6 months.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [Send](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/send.html) SOAP Object.  You can retrieve and store this historical send data with WSProxy.

I've outlined that process here: https://sprignaturemoves.com/retrieving-and-storing-aggregated-send-data/

ID -> JobID

It's a good, historical data set that can be be used as a basis for many different kinds of reporting.

There's also a similar object for Triggered Sends -- [TriggeredSendSummary](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/triggeredsendsummary.html): https://sprignaturemoves.com/retrieving-and-storing-aggregated-triggered-send-data/

Comment: Hi Adam , its such a coincidence, i was actually looking at the very same object , but using SOAP api as  i was checking if this was ok. Thanks